# What does "30 coin" mean?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Mr Universe says to the Operative:

> Mr Universe: There. Toss me my **30 coin**, but I got a news wave for you...

Then Operative stabs him. He orders his crew:

> Operative: Call in every ship in the quadrant. We'll meet them in the air.

What does "30 coin" mean?

Comment: Reference to 30 pieces of silver that Judas received in the Bible for betraying Jesus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mr Universe is betraying the crew by luring them to their deaths. Apparently in return for money ("coin")

> The operative removed the sword from his briefcase even as Mr. Universe turned his chair around toward him. "There. Toss me my thirty coin, but I got a newswave for you, friend—"
>
> Whatever information this man wished to impart was lost as the operative ran him through. Mr. Universe seemed surprised, as if he could have all this information at his disposal, **yet be wholly unaware of the usual fate of traitors.**
>
> <sub><sup>Serenity: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

The traditional (biblical) payment for being a traitor is 30 pieces of silver.

> And said unto them, What will ye give me, and I will deliver him unto you? And **they covenanted with [Judas] for thirty pieces of silver.**
>
> <sub><sup>Matthew 26:15</sup></sub>

Comment: That makes it sound as if he were a traitor from the viewpoint of the Alliance, but from their perspective, wouldn't someone turning in to the authorities a bunch of murderous, thieving pirates that were a national security threat be the opposite of treason?

Comment: @Adamant - The Operative is very much of the opinion that you need to be loyal to your home team, regardless of which side you're playing on. We're supposed to see him (an amoral man serving the state) as the diametric opposite of Mal (a moral man living a life outside of the law)

Comment: @Adamant that's exactly what Judas did - turn a dangerous threat over to the Jewish authorities by betraying him

Comment: @OrangeDog - Precisely, and *they* did not view him as a traitor, but he was rather rewarded with what was probably a large payment (since the historicity of the payment, the denomination of the coins, whether they were even made of silver or rather gold, and for that matter the existence of Judas and his betrayal are all uncertain).